# CKEditor ckfinder headers is not working in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ckeditor, ckfinder

I have built a custom classic editor using ckeditor online builder and used it in my code and it works fine.
I configured the editor to use ckfinder for uploading images like this:

```
config={{
          ckfinder: {
            headers: {
              "X-CSRF-TOKEN": "CSFR-Token",
              Authorization: `Bearer <JSON WEB TOKEN>`,
            },
            uploadUrl: `/api/Articles/${location.state.state.id}/Attach`,
             withCredentials: true,
          },
}}
```

the problem is it doesn't send the headers along with the request and as the result the request fails and the image won't be uploaded.
Am i doing something wrong?